# What do the Stack Exchange offices look like?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I was curious to know about Stack Overflow and searched on Google to see what Stack Overflow offices look like and what the environment is like.

I want to know about employees, but unfortunately I couldn't get any single video on YouTube.

Google is a huge corporation and even they provide a view of their complex, people and environment, so then why is Stack Overflow behind on this?

Comment: https://www.google.com/maps/@40.7084586,-74.0072479,3a,75y,87.78h,79.25t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1sKLfEpmHGEUoAAAQIt-PpQw!2e0!3e2!7i13312!8i6656

Comment: Aside from the video service, what is 'Plex'?

Comment: @JonW plex means units or structure ..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

tl;dr:  Working here is awesome. But you wanted detail, so...

**You can literally take a virtual tour of our NYC office.** You seem to be particularly interested in the work environment, so you may enjoy the [Google "See Inside" Street View of our NYC Headquarters](https://www.google.com/maps/@40.7087495,-74.0068409,3a,75y,77.89h,63.86t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1s5w4SMuf8pAoAAAGusUzJiw!2e0!3e2!7i13312!8i6656). (If you're going for a full tour, note that there are 2 floors, and you can access them by clicking the "1" and "2" on the right side of the image.)

**I'm not sure why anyone would want to watch videos of the likes of us, but there are a few on our page on [The Muse](https://www.themuse.com/companies/stackoverflow).** And most of em are literally about working here, so that may help you get some of the color you're looking for.

**[Our blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/) has a number of posts that touch on our working environment and how we do things here.** Patrick Hofman already referenced two of the most relevant ones, but there are a bunch of others that touch on how we work.

Comment: I click on one button on a link, and I see this. **Skeet Emulator.** Explanation please? (i.e. Cool! I want one!)

Comment: @Zizouz212, unfortunately, that hardware is based on entirely proprietary technology.  Besides, you need a cold fusion engine to power it in any case.  Or it might be a joke. :P

Comment: @Jaydles you are one who got me.. Basically I am looking how organizations provides environment that employees could work in better way. Personally I am JavaEE developer and wanted to create such awesome environment in my home workspace. So where I would love to work :) Thanks that is answer

Answer (score 9):

Stack Exchange is very open on its employees and its working environment.

See here for example to see the people that work there: https://stackexchange.com/about/team.

A peak in their offices can be found in this blog post: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/why-we-still-believe-in-private-offices/.

Answer (score 6):

The list of the users who work for Stack Overflow is already given in this question. [Who are the users that work for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95625/357396)

The [details](https://stackoverflow.com/company/management) of the company management are also present.

There's also a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wpqE8OSWrU) on Youtube which takes a tour of the [Stack Exchange office](https://www.google.co.in/maps/uv?hl=en&pb=!1s0x48761ca88457abb7:0xa801def78c80b065!2m22!2m2!1i80!2i80!3m1!2i20!16m16!1b1!2m2!1m1!1e1!2m2!1m1!1e3!2m2!1m1!1e5!2m2!1m1!1e4!2m2!1m1!1e6!3m1!7e115!4s/maps/place/stack%2Bexchange%2Blondon%2Baddress/@51.5253214,-0.0905482,3a,75y,172.56h,90t/data%3D*213m4*211e1*213m2*211sdRC8mZDd7vVZjTzgcLtX_A*212e0*214m2*213m1*211s0x48761ca88457abb7:0xa801def78c80b065!5sstack+exchange+london+address+-+Google+Search&imagekey=!1e2!2sdRC8mZDd7vVZjTzgcLtX_A&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZhNjBqqzWAhVGvI8KHWAyAWIQpx8IejAK) at Old Street, London. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_2qg899Vgk) is the video of the London office warming party where many developers including Joel Spolsky attended.

Google street view is enabled to watch the outside of the office there. There is awesome wall art, large monitors, adjustable table and the list goes on.