# How to search for questions from ♦ users (moderators / Valued Associates <--- employees )?

Tags: support, search, moderators, company, stack-exchange-team

We have [announcements](/questions/tagged/announcements) on Meta SE but it could be used by anyone, by the other hand we have [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) on Meta sites but it's not always used and it isn't kept forever.

Is there a way to search for posts made by ♦ users other than creating a list of their user ids?

I know that looking at the posts of ♦ user (moderator / <strike>employee</strike>  Valued Associate) will not assure that those posts are official posts as they could reflect they personal opinions I still would like to find an easier way to scan the posts made by these users.

Related

- [Can we be notified about official posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186614/289691)
- [¿Cómo encontrar las publicaciones oficiales?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2659/65) (How to find the official posts?)
- [Who are the Community Team, and what do they do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99338/289691)
- [Full list of Moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109875/289691)
- [Keep "Employee" on the profile of SE employees on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161197/289691)
- [Employee profiles are now marked with a “Staff” indicator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331654/289691)

Comment: The API does have info on who is an employee: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304217/158100 you could extend that to scan their posts. Are you interested in that info from just a single site or across multiple sites? Also relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291587/158100

Comment: @rene For now I'm interested on searching posts on a single Meta site, and on first place on posts made here, on Meta SE.

Comment: @Rubén One thing you sort of can't forget is ... not all staff have diamonds. A lot of people don't realize that but, it's true. There are lots of staff who don't need to be moderators here (which is what the diamond represents), so they're not. :)

Comment: @Catija Thank you. For now it's fine to let their posts out of the search results I'm looking for.

Comment: Related: [How to find all recent posts and comments by SE staff?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340693/398063)

Answer (score 6):

I do not think that this would be useful information because you would need to distinguish questions asked by current/past moderators and staff before and/or after they became or ceased being moderators and staff.

Also, even when elected/appointed as moderators or staff, posts from such users often represent their user opinion rather than official policy.

When wearing their moderator/staff hat rather than replying as an ordinary user they will sometimes/often mention that in their posts.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thougths. I know that looking at the posts of ♦ users (moderator / employee) will not assure that those posts are official posts as they could reflect they personal opinions I still would like to find an easier way to scan the posts made by these users. Any thought about that?

Comment: Elected/appointed moderators/employees are almost always highly engaged site users.  As users they have a user-id and a profile page on each site that they participate in, so their posts are already retrievable.  When acting as moderators/employees rather than users the content of their post will sometimes/often say that they are wearing that hat while making that post.

Comment: I feel making this possible could do more harm than good. People could search for questions from moderators/employees for malicious intent, such as repeated downvoting or inappropriate comments for vengeance against the site or to attract negative attention from them. At the same time, I don't think it'd be useful knowledge. Similar to what PolyGeo said, posts from such users often represent their opinion instead of official policy. This would mean that their questions are likely to be of no difference to questions from other good users.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't currently possible to search for questions only made by moderators/employees. However, you can look up the list of moderators for a site, for example [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators). You can then look up the profile of a particular moderator and search for their questions and answers in a similar vein to searching for any user's questions and answers.

Comment: Thank you. The proposed solution is very similar to the list of users ids mentioned in the question. I will add an example to the question.

Comment: I forgot that site search doesn't support the OR operator to search for posts of a group of spectific users, so I dedided to post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The [announcements](/questions/tagged/announcements) tag is *one* possible way that employees can post updates, streams of consciousness, ad-hoc data that might be of interest or similar artifacts that aren't ideally suited for our blog audience. However, we've gotta implement an archetype to accommodate these posts (and make the tag, whatever it ends up being) reserved specifically for that use.

Searching based on *who* wrote it is problematic for a bunch of reasons pointed out by others, but it also excludes the *many* instances where we saw something that someone in the community wrote and just up-voted that instead. Not *all* questions about policy require a direct response from us, *especially* if it's in an area where we'd rather leave it to the autonomy of any given community.

What you're looking for from a *practical* standpoint is probably ***consensus***, where you can find *some* kind of agreement on a given topic even if you have to take a lack of a reply from us on it as a tacit endorsement. Meta is quite frankly *really* bad at this, and that's something we're going to need to tackle. Discussions happen, stuff gets voted on, people go back to what they were doing thinking it's all settled and a year later, nobody can be *quite* sure anymore, especially someone new just trying to grok policy and the rules.

What we really need is some kinda process for *referendum*, which I plan to kick off a discussion about later this year. We might need to just support formal polls, and have some way of attaching them to questions (Trivia: they've existed in the database structure for eons, we just never built them).

I don't have a definite ETA other than this is something that blocks a more efficient, unobstructed flow of community governance into more official things like the help center, so it's important, as soon as we figure out how in the heck we can do it.

More pressing right now: Question lifecycle, quality, tooling on the main site. But this needs to be in place, too, in order to support that.

Comment: Thanks you very much for sharing your vision about questions about policy, processes and the pressing issues. I'm aware that searching is not "the solution" but it's what we have at hand for now.

Answer (score 1):

A this time it's not possible to use a single search query to get all the posts from a group of specific users.

Since on Meta the Users > Moderator page is blanck, below is a list of the URL to search the posts of each diamond user on Meta SE.

Note: At this time the list only include CM's. I took the CM user id's from [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341/289691) to [Who are the Community Team, and what do they do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99338/289691)

- Robert Cartaino: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:98786
- Shog9: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:811
- hairboat: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:165581
- Grace Note: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:146126
- Tim Post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:50049
- Jon Ericson: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:1438
- Nicolas Chabanovsky: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:274323
- Juan M: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:296470
- animuson: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:141525
- JNat: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:208518
- Catija: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:284336

---

Users who have the ♦ on MSE, posted an [announcement](/questions/tagged/announcement) but aren't CMs

2018

- Joe Friend: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:354333
- Adam Lear: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:155160
- Taryn: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:164200

2017

- Tom Limoncelli: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:222882
- Nick Craver: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:135201

---

Users who currently haven't the ♦ that made offial posts (maybe without using [announcement](/questions/tagged/announcement), [featured](/questions/tagged/featured))

- Laura: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:166017

Comment: This probably only applies to me but... about 95% of what I've written has nothing to do with being staff because I've only worked here for about two months as of right now. :D

Comment: @Catija  .... 6 to 8 weeks .... ?

Comment: @Catija Do you use [tag:announcements] on your official questions on MSE?

Comment: Its also worth noting, there's a few former staff who don't have diamonds *now* who might have posted "official" posts in the past. And a few staff who choose not to get a diamond but are the "authoritative" source for things