# Who fixes issue reports of Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderator-tags, stack-exchange-team

There are moderators who apply a "status tag" (also known as red tag) on questions tagged as bugs and feature-request, e.g. ([status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) etc.)

Are these moderators also the developers of Stack Exchange issue reporting system?

Comment: See [Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75189/289905), [Who are the Community Team, and what do they do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99338/289905) for information about who can apply “status” tags and moderators in general.

Comment: _“On Meta sites, a few tags (shown in red) can only be added or removed by moderators, e.g. [meta-tag:faq], and all status tags.”_ — [Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100153/289905)

Comment: [Stack Overflow’s About page](https://stackoverflow.com/company), [Who are the users that work for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95625/289905), [What super-powers does SE staff have, that diamond moderators do not have?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158215/289905).

Comment: I could not find the information about 'who has the privilege to put a "status" tag' in the above links mentioned. Thanks though :)

Comment: I created a new tag for that question category. Maybe answers for this question should be transferred to the tag wiki there.

Comment: If any one of your questions is not fully answered by one of the duplicates, then you could [edit] this question to make it more focused and cease being a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are these moderators also the developers of Stack Exchange issue reporting system?

Sometimes, but not always. On every Stack Exchange meta site, any user who is a moderator with a diamond can add/remove the "red tags", however this does not mean that person also works for Stack Exchange. None of the moderators listed in the "moderators" tab of the /Users page of the site is SE employee, as they can't also be a site moderator.

Stack Exchange employees (including developers) might have a diamond on any site, however they'll not be listed as moderators and their role is not to moderate the sites. However, they also have the power to add/remove red tags exactly as the moderators, and they often to this to mark bug as fixed (or declined).

The only people who actually fix the bugs are SE developers, not the site moderators, who don't work for SE and don't have access to the code anyway.

However, site moderators might put a [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) for example for a bug that was fixed a while ago, and the developer who fixed it forgot to do it themselves. If ordinary user spots a bug report which is clearly fixed, but lacking the completed tag, they can also flag for mod attention and ask for the tag to be added.

Comment: How do the site moderators know when if a bug is resolved by the developer or not? Do they perform testing of the issue?

Comment: @Aadi I mean only the obvious things, e.g. bug about wrong color or wrong wording of something. I do not expect the site mods to go and check into this if it requires more than a minute.

Answer (score 4):

Meta's slightly unique. There's different sorts of mods here. I'm a community mod. We're a relatively new thing. I handle most sorts of flags I come across but I don't really have any insight over development - so we tend not to handle these.

At the moment, as such we leave those flags for the community managers, developers and other employees.

On other sites or if it's something we can confirm is resolved or won't fix we might, but on MSE chances are it'll need to wait for an employee.